# Mixing global/static views with dynamic views in an Angular JS application

Tags: angularjs

I have a Yeoman scaffolded Angular-JS+Twitter Bootstrap seed project.  I use the Bootstrap navbar on every page of the site for, you guessed it, navigation.

What is the best way to include this in an Angular project... directly within index.html, as a view?  Ideally I ought to encapsulate the entire navbar div as a template and simply call it out, just not sure exactly how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it should be included on every 'page', include it in your index.html with ng-include.

You would have something like:

```
<body>
   <div ng-include='"path/to/partials/navbar.html"'></div>
   ...
</body>
```